# which minimal android and ios versions for expo sdk 22 and 36?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'd like to update my app from old expo 22 to current 36.
which minimal android and ios versions for expo sdk 22 and 36?
or is there difference in minimal version to run app builded with expo 22 and 36 on android/ios?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware all versions of the Expo SDK support Android 4.4 and greater (Android SDK 20 and greater). *There is no need to set minimum Android SDK.* If you want more control over the metadata you need to eject from expo and use ExpoKit.

[Upgrading expo SDK walkthrough](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/upgrading-expo-sdk-walkthrough/)